# Interpreting scatterplots

Tags: scatterplot

I am working with an agricultural data with the aim to establishing bean-lines that are resistant to bruchid infestation. I want to find the relationship between some variables (mostly number of holes in a seed against the number of insects that emerge from the seed). I have generated some scatter plots but cannot determine the relationship between them. I need some help in determining this relationship.

The images below are the scatter plots.

[image: the scatter plot between seeds with one hole against the number of bruchids observed]
[image: the scatter plot between seeds with three holes against the number of bruchids observed]
[image: the scatter plot between seeds with five holes against the number of bruchids observed]
[image: the scatter plot between seeds with more than five holes against the number of bruchids observed]

Comment: Why are you using these strange proportions of seeds with different ranges of holes? Why not use the number of holes directly?

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you  have overplotted points. Try jittering.